# Exiting in custom session handler

Tags: php, session

I am really new to custom session handlers, so I really want to understand how is it works.

1) I just copied the [example code](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) from php.net, and mofidied a little:

```
public function write($id, $data) {
    die('xxx');
    return file_put_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id", $data) === false ? false : true;
}
```

As you see, I wrote a die. I run this code:

```
$S = new MySession\SessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($S, true);
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
var_dump($_SESSION);
die('End');
```

output is:

```
array (size=1)
  'foo' => string 'bar' (length=3)

Endxxx
```

How is it possible? More intresting that if I put a `session_destroy();` before `die('End')`, then `xxx` does not appears. Is it something with output buffering?

2) This question has deleted. Answered in the comments.

Comment: *"I tried to started the session like this"* - what version of php are you using? `session_start(['save_path' => TMP_PATH . '/session']);` that method was only introduced in php 7. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php *"7.0.0  The options parameter was added."* `bool session_start ([ array $options = [] ] )`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Damn, you are right. I am using 5.6.1

Comment: Kind of had a feeling about that: *"Spidey sense told me"* ;-) so you can't use that method. I should have posted an answer for it. as per original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42306192/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've changed it to 7.1.1 at my workplace, and I've forget to do it at home. What a mess...

Comment: So it's another "Happy ending" then ;-)